# Unable to delete resources from wso2 developer studio registry project

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I have created new Registry Project in developer studio and added few resources to it. 
But i am unable to delete those resources from registry project. Can anybody tell me how i can delete registry resources from developer studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the resources you want to delete from the Registry Resources Project from the Eclipse Project Explorer view
2. Right Click -> Delete
3. It will prompt the generic Eclipse resource delete dialog asking you to confirm the deletion. There you will be able to see the preview of the result of deletion as well.
4. Then click OK to confirm the deletion and Eclipse will update the Registry Resources Project with necessary changes.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: I knew the steps but issue was with my wso2 developer studio, which was not showing any option after right clicking the resources.

Comment: Eclipse should display the normal Eclipse Right Click context menu for all the resources for the resources in your project. Can you attach an image of the situation you have because it seems to be very unusual for Eclipse not to display that Context Menu.

Comment: Now its working fine after creating new work space for wso2 developer studio.